# java.lang.NullPointerException in Arrayadapter in android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

Null pointer exception during adding data on arrayadapter. getting error

> E/AndroidRuntime(9233): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(9233):java.lang.NullPointerException  E/AndroidRuntime(9233):   at
>   co.adapter.TopicCustomDisplayArrayAdapter.getView(TopicCustomDisplayArrayAdapter.java:415)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(9233):   at co.utils.TwoWayView.obtainView(TwoWayView.java:5599)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9233):   at
>   co.utils.TwoWayView.onMeasure(TwoWayView.java:3899)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9233):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12773)

Doing this on my code:

```
 private View convertView;
 Holder holderText = null;
public TopicCustomDisplayArrayAdapter(Context context,
        ArrayList<fieldModel> arrayList) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_display, arrayList);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    customTopicAd = arrayList;

    mcontext = context;
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisc(true).considerExifParams(true)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View cv, ViewGroup parent) {

    convertView = cv;

    AdTypeString = customTopic.get(position).getAd_Type();

    if (AdTypeString.equalsIgnoreCase("Text Ads")) {

        if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.text_view,
            parent, false);

        holderText = new Holder();
        holderText.textRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.relativeTextAdView);

        convertView.setTag(holderText);
        } else {
        holderText = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        int widthTextAd = Integer.parseInt(customTopicAd.get(position)
            .getWidht());
        int heightTextAd = Integer.parseInt(customTopicAd.get(position)
            .getHeight();

        holderText.textRelativeLayout.getLayoutParams().width = widthTextAd;
        holderText.textRelativeLayout.getLayoutParams().height = heightTextAd;
        } else if (AdTypeString.equalsIgnoreCase("Image Ads")) {
       // display another layout
        }
   return convertView;
   }
  public static class Holder {
// Display Ads Resrouces

public RelativeLayout textRelativeLayout;


}
```

height and widht getting properly but could not set height and widht on relative layout. getting on this line:

**holderText.textRelativeLayout.getLayoutParams().width = widthTextAd;
            holderText.textRelativeLayout.getLayoutParams().height = heightTextAd;**

Any idea how to correction this error. here arraylist size is 5.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `getLayoutParams()` causes nullpointer because `textRelativeLayout` has not have any layout params or any size.If you want to set textRelativeLayout's size,you may consider to set layoutParams of this view.
So Change

```
holderText.textRelativeLayout.getLayoutParams().width = widthTextAd;
holderText.textRelativeLayout.getLayoutParams().height = heightTextAd;
```

to

```
TwoWayView.LayoutParams lp = new TwoWayView.LayoutParams(widthTextAd, heightTextAd);
holderText.textRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: I added **LayoutParams LP = new LayoutParams(widthTextAd, heightTextAd);
     holderText.textRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(LP);** and still getting same error. if i add your above relative layout code, the casting problem, :java.lang.ClassCastException: **android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to co.utils.TwoWayView$LayoutParams**

Comment: Still getting same error on line:      **holderText.textRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(LP);**

Comment: Use it as `TwoWayView.LayoutParams lp = new TwoWayView.LayoutParams(widthTextAd, heightTextAd);` see edit.

Comment: sorry, it could not help for me. still getting same type of error.i dont know how to get such type of error. thank you for your comments.

Comment: i think, holderText not recognized properly.but i defined already, why getting error? if i remove this line of code then next error comes holderText.textviewName. so any idea?

Comment: use it as `holderText.textRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new TwoWayView.LayoutParams(widthTextAd, heightTextAd));`

Comment: sorry sir, it also could not help for me, still same error.